# Getting Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angul arJS testability and angular testability are undefined

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to run a Protractor Test using PageObjectModel (module.exports mechanism).

My HomePageObjects.js is like below -

```
//Get the page objects to spec files in the form of key-value pair

/*module.exports.Homepage=
{
        Name:element(by.name('name')),
        Email:element(by.name('email')),
        Password:element(by.id("exampleInputPassword1")),
        Checkbox: element(by.css("input[id='exampleCheck1']")),
//      element(by.cssContainingText("[id='exampleFormControlSelect1'] option", "Female")).click(); //One way to select a value
        Gender:element(by.css("select[id='exampleFormControlSelect1']")).click().element(by.css("select[id='exampleFormControlSelect1']>option:nth-child(2)")), //Another way
//      to select a value
        EmploymentStatus:element(by.id("inlineRadio1")),
        SubmitBtn:element(by.buttonText("Submit")),
        Success:element(by.css("div[class*='success']"))

};*/

function HomePage1()

{
    this.Name=element(by.name('name'));
    this.Email=element(by.name('email'));
    this.Password=element(by.id("exampleInputPassword1"));
    this.Checkbox= element(by.css("input[id='exampleCheck1']"))
//  element(by.cssContainingText("[id='exampleFormControlSelect1'] option", "Female")).click(); //One way to select a value
    this.Gender=element(by.css("select[id='exampleFormControlSelect1']")).click().element(by.css("select[id='exampleFormControlSelect1']>option:nth-child(2)")); //Another way
//  to select a value
    this.EmploymentStatus=element(by.id("inlineRadio1"));
    this.SubmitBtn=element(by.buttonText("Submit"));
    this.Success=element(by.css("div[class*='success']"));
}

Homepage1 = new HomePage1();



module.exports={
        Homepage1
}
```

When I am trying to execute the spec (which is below), I am getting error.

I have tried with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`; but of no avail.

```
describe('Submit Form', function(){

    var obj = require("./HomePageObjects.js"); // Access the objects from HomePageObjects.js


    it('Test Submit Form', function(){

        browser.get("https://qaclickacademy.github.io/protocommerce/");

        obj.Homepage1.Name.sendKeys("Prabodh");

    });

})
```

Can anyone please help me?

Error -

```
Message:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angul
arJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either be
cause this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navig
ation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v
4gXM for details"
```

Comment: What if you remove `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` and remove `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`? I just executed it like this and it worked for me - no errors and I see text being entered into the input.

Comment: @alecxe - Tried your suggestions, same issue.

Comment: What are your protractor, chromedriver and chrome versions? Also, please post your protractor config. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe - 

Protractor - 5.4.1
Chrome - 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver - 2.45

configuration.js -

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['SubmitForm.js'],
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'chrome'
 }
};

Comment: try to add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER=true` in your config

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding var obj = require("./HomePageObjects.js");  inside it() block instead of describe() block.